# Detect context in Self-hosted Web Api

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-web-api, owin, quartz.net

In my current project I have a windows service that periodically runs tasks (TopShelf/Quartz.net). Instead of creating a separate project for a web service I want to add this to the windows service using the self-hosting features available in OWIN. This also has the added benifit of not needing to deploy in IIS.

When I'm going to implement my  Data Access Layer (DAL) I'll be getting into problems however.

All my database actions are done within a UnitOfWork that is stored in a request state and in the end there is a commit/rollback. The context determines the lifecycle of the UnitOfWork (request state). In a console app I would use a PerThreadRequest state. In a web environment I have a PerHttpRequestState. This would mean that the scope of the UnitOfWork is per thread or per HttpRequest.

In my current project however I have the mix of both console (Quartz jobs) and web (web api calls). These both need to use the DAL but aren't able to use the same request state as it's another context.

I could solve this manually. When using the DAL from the quartz jobs, have it use the PerThreadRequestState and when using the DAL from web api calls use the PerHttpRequestState but this is a messy solution.
When using the DAL it should detect in wich context it is operating and react accordingly.

But how would I go about detecting the context?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this, using Castle Windsor (although the principle is the same with other IOC/DI frameworks)

```
if(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId != null) //it's a web app
{
    container.Register(
         Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<PerHttpRequestState>());
}
else //it's a windows app
{
    container.Register(
         Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<PerThreadRequestState>());
}
```

Having said that, there are caveats in using a UoW on a thread lifestyle:

- Firstly, you will have to make sure that your UoW is thread safe (what happens if two or more jobs end up accessing the UoW at the same time?)
- More importantly, Quartz.NET uses a ThreadPool internally so it will not necessarily create a new thread every time a job is launched, but reuse an existing one. This can lead to leakage; your UoW can be de-facto shared between jobs. What you may want is to use a custom ***PerQuartzJob*** lifestyle.

Both of these, however, depend on what sort of usage you intend to put your quartz service through. If you don't have many, long-running, potentially overlapping CRUD jobs, then they are less of a concern.

Comment: My UoW is thread safe because of the [ThreadStatic] tag used. Your point about the potential for leakage in the ThreadPool is correct though. I hadn't thought of that. The pool contains 10 threads and these have a ThreadStatic state each. Consecutive jobs run by the same thread could potentially have access to the same state. Within the scope of the Job however the UoW is surrounded with using(){} so it should be disposed when the next job is run on the same thread.

Comment: Your suggestion however is for registering the correct UoW implementation in the container but I need both.

The WebApi is self hosted in the service so calls to the webapi are per http request. Quartz jobs run in the same service should be PerThread (or PerQuartzJob).

I shouldn't mix both of these in the same service? Or I would need a way to identify on the fly in what context the UoW is being used.

In both the webapi method and quartz job execution the HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId property is null though.